# Set innerHTML of DOM with template tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently working on a Vue project, and I am trying to set the innerHTML of a HTML element with a template tag. For example:

```
let divElem = document.getElementById('divElem')
let innerHTMLContent = `<template><div>test</div></template>`
divElem.innerHTML = innerHTMLContent
```

However, the content of the innerHTMLContent does not get rendered. Instead, it shows #documentfragment below the template tag when I do the Inspect -> Elements. I strongly suspect is the template tag that is causing the issue.

Is there any advice on how I can get the innerHTML to render the template tag?

Comment: I have no Explanation but you can us:     divElem.append(innerHTMLContent);    to get what you want.

Comment: This may help you too:   https://code-boxx.com/javascript-document-fragment/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into the DocumentFragment Pitfall here. You are right that this has to do with the template.

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#avoiding_documentfragment_pitfall

as `<template>` is being used to render content later on with e.g. Javascript this wont work as changes are expected after adding the template to the DOM, probably not with it.